# How can I install drivers for Realtek RTL8811AU?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

How to install drivers for Realtek RTL8811AU? Ubuntu 21.04, kernel version - 5.11.0-16.17? Tried multiple versions from github but the problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the utility of RTL8812AU driver for  RTL8811AU chipset. You may try installing dkms (dynamic kernel module) of that driver by the command `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`

Comment: It did not help

Comment: I found a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @AlbertodaSilva! Can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - for me it helped:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/5.7.0 --all
sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 --all
sudo dkms remove 8812au/5.9.3.2_37279.20201012 --all
```

Then you can install the package with following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelebek333/kablosuz/ubuntu focal main"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 23E50C670722A6D9
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

From [TPLink Archer t2u+ & Kernel 5.10 (rtl8812)](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=344721) on Linux Mint Forums

Answer (score 0):

## Linux 5.10+

### (Debian *Bullseye* and Ubuntu *Focal* onwards)

…*currently* requires a patched version of the `rtl8812au` driver. It worked for me on *Debian* and you may use that modified version as long as no "official" solutions are available.

You can download it from [here](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)* and it will appear in `$ sudo dkms status` as module `8812au` version `4.2.3`. Load it using `$ sudo modprobe 8812au` and after a few seconds your card should appear. Don't trust the reported connection quality, go near your router and if it does not connect automatically, reconfigure the connection manually. The driver will be recompiled automatically when a new kernel is installed but check if the connection works with the new kernel before removing the old ones.

<sub>*unofficial/unstable, do not use in production. Instructions included in the readme.</sub>